# Heap and Stack memory storage in C++

Tags: c++

I am a little bit confused about where certain members of my following simple program will get storage?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Human
{
    public:
        int *age; //where will it get storage?
        string *name; //where will it get storage?

        Human(string name, int age)
        {
            this->name = new string; //string will got into heap
            this->age = new int; //int will go into heap

            *(this->name) = name;
            *(this->age) = age;
        }

        void display()
        {
            cout << "Name : " << *name << " Age : " << *age << endl;
        }

        ~Human()
        {
            cout << "Freeing memory";
            delete(name);
            delete(age);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Human *human = new Human("naveen", 24); //human object will go into heap
    human->display();
    delete(human);
    return 0;
}
```

I have created a class `Human` object using `new` operator. Hence, it will definitely get storage in heap. But where will its properties `age` and `name` will get the storage?

Comment: Since you also allocate `age` and `name` with `new` it'll be allocated on the heap too.

Comment: @JameyD : Yeah that I knew, but where will the `age` and `name` pointers occupy the memory? Their memory blocks will surely be in heap as you said.

Comment: Yes the pointers themselves are stored in the heap.

Comment: @0x499602D2 : because I used `new Human`? If yes, that means if I simply did `Human human("naveen",24)`, will then the pointers go into stack?

Comment: 'If my object is allocated on the heap, are its member variables, which are part of the object, also stored on the heap?' I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The member variables `age` and `name` which are pointers to `int` and `string` respectively will be stored on the heap or the stack depending on how you create an object of the `Human` class.

Stored on the stack:

```
Human human("naveen", 24); // human object is stored on the stack and thus it's pointer members `age` and `name` are stored on the stack too
```

Stored on the heap:

```
Human *human = new Human("naveen", 24); // human object is stored on the heap and thus it's pointer members `age` and `name` are stored on the heap too
```

The code you provided :

```
Human *human = new Human("naveen", 24); //human object will go into heap
```

`//human object will go into heap` merely means that all members of the `Human` class are stored on the heap.